# Octokit Client create Repo for User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, octokit

I have ruby on rails app and I'm using Octokit to connect to an enterprise GitHub (GHE) that I'm hosting myself.

Due to certain constraints, new users are signing up on my app and I create accounts for them on my GHE instance, which means I never have access to their GHE passwords.

Using an admin account for my Octokit client, I need to be able to create repos for my users, only having access to their GHE username.

Anyone have any ideas how to do this? Is there a way to pretend to be the user, or to create the repo and then transfer ownership? I know I can create the repo under the admin account and add the user as a collaborator, but I would like to just create the repo under the user's account in the first place.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well I haven't been able to figure out how to accomplish this task the way I described above, however I did find a workaround.

My Octokit client is my GHE admin account and I just create each repo under my admin's name. Then I add my user as a collaborator. On the backend, it looks funky, but the users don't see any of this because I keep track of state.

If anyone has a way of solving this issue as I described it above, that would be great!